# Blocking incoming PayPal payments?

Tags: paypal

I would like to temporarily block incoming payments to my PayPal account.

I've looked under `Profile` -> `Settings` but can't find any option to block payments.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

This setting is available in **premier** accounts, but not in **personal** accounts.

Click on `Profile` > `My Selling Preferences` > Look under `Getting paid and managing risk` and you'll see the `Block Payments` link.

You can do any of the following:

- Block payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold.
- Block accidental payments: (You may prevent accidental payments by blocking duplicate invoice IDs).
- Block Payments from users who initiate payments from the Pay Anyone subtab of the Send Money tab.
- Block Pay with eCheque or German bank transfer for all website payments except eBay.
- Block payments from Student account users under 18 years old.
- Display "Add Instructions to Seller" text input field.
- Change the way PAYPAL appears on your credit card statements.

But **you can't block all payments being sent to your account or email address**. (I was curious about this so I checked with PayPal support.)

If you're having problems give PayPal a call on +35314369004 (UK/Ireland) or +14029357733 (USA).

Comment: I don't have a premium account. I have personal account and I can't find your setting

Comment: @yes123 updated the answer, it seems this is only applicable for premier accounts, there are no options for this in personal accounts. Try giving them a call on the number in the answer.